# Can't get imageView with picasso

Tags: android, json, android-fragments, picasso

```
OrderTab

public class Order_Tab extends Fragment{
    Context context;
    JSONObject Tokenobj=null;
    String token;
    String token_type;
    String title;
    String price;
    String status;
    String symbol;
    String imageurl;
    private ImageView imageOrdersN;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    JSONParser jsonParser=new JSONParser();
    private static final String URL_ORDERS="http://baymd.myterranet.com/api/orders/";
    private static final String TAG_IMAGE="orderImage";
    private static final String TAG_TITLE="title";
    private static final String TAG_PRICE="price";
    private static final String TAG_PRICESYMBOL="symbol";
    private static final String TAG_PSTATUS="orderPaymentStatus";

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> orderList;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_orders_tabs,container,false);
        imageOrdersN= (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageOrders);

        return v;

    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



        try {
            Tokenobj = new JSONObject (getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("cjson"));
            Log.d("JObject", Tokenobj.toString());
            token = Tokenobj.getString("access_token");
            token_type = Tokenobj.getString("token_type");
            Log.d("Token", token);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        orderList=new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        new LoadOrders().execute();
    }
    public void parse(int counter){

        try{
            List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_ORDERS, "GET", param, token);
            JSONObject name = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");
            JSONObject orders = data.getJSONObject("orders");
            JSONObject country = orders.getJSONObject("US");
            Log.d("JSON NAME",name.toString());
            Log.d("JSON ORDERS",orders.toString());
            Log.d("JSON COUNTRY", country.toString());
            for(;counter < 20;counter++) {
                JSONObject c = country.getJSONObject(String.valueOf(counter));
                imageurl = c.getString(TAG_IMAGE);
                Log.d("IDK", imageurl);
                title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE).substring(0, 20);
                price = c.getString(TAG_PRICE);
                status = c.getString(TAG_PSTATUS);
                symbol = c.getString(TAG_PRICESYMBOL);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            parse(counter+1);
        }
    }
    class LoadOrders extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog=new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading orders ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            parse(19);


            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();


            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(TAG_TITLE,title);
            map.put(TAG_PRICE, price);
            map.put(TAG_PSTATUS, status);
            map.put(TAG_PRICESYMBOL,symbol);
            map.put(TAG_IMAGE,imageurl);
            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            orderList.add(map);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

                pDialog.dismiss();
            ListView list= (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);
            ListAdapter adapter=new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(),orderList,R.layout.fragment_order_list_item,
                    new String[]{TAG_PRICE,TAG_TITLE,TAG_PSTATUS,TAG_PRICESYMBOL,TAG_IMAGE},new int[]{R.id.price,R.id.title,R.id.pstatus,R.id.symbol,R.id.imageOrders});
            Picasso.with(getView().getContext()).load(R.drawable.usa).into(imageOrdersN);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
}
```

> LogCat

```
09-29 22:49:54.219    4416-4416/baymd.baymdfinal E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null.
            at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:479)
            at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:462)
            at baymd.baymdfinal.Order_Tab$LoadOrders.onPostExecute(Order_Tab.java:134)
            at baymd.baymdfinal.Order_Tab$LoadOrders.onPostExecute(Order_Tab.java:100)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

> ImageLink from Json

```
http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NzE2WDcxNg==/z/ObwAAOSwPe1T5ENW/$_12.JPG?set_id=8800005007
```

I have understod the fact that the problem is in the ImageView but i don't know how to fix it , believe me i searched the web for a solution and i failed to find one,

If other materials are needed fell free to ask

[XML for fragment_orders_tabs and fragment_order_list_item](http://paste.ofcode.org/UGthERGbsHAz6gFupjp25L)

Comment: Why do you have the Picasso loading line repeated in onPostExecute()?

Comment: sorry ,i editet , i forgot to delete it , cause i copied it almost everywere to figure out the problem but i failed

Comment: Put all your code that is inside OnCreate() and below super.onCreate() inside onCreateView() and retry it. make sure imageOrdersN belongs to fragment_orders_tabs layout

Comment: i put the code as you said , still the same error , but the imageOrdersN doesn't belong to fragment_orders_tab but to fragment_order_list_item

Comment: That explains everything. Then, you cannot declare it as being part of fragment_orders_tab, like you are doing inside onCreateView(). You need to put that Picasso code inside your CustomAdapter getView() method or something like that.

Comment: sorry and thank you , i'm a begginer i don't have a custom getView adapter all i have it's this http://paste.ofcode.org/EynHgvQQ5DPr7BFL2S8Q3A

Comment: If you want to have one dinamically loaded Image per list item, you have to make it inside getView() method of your CustomAdapter. Search for it on SO.